# Sharing edit page among controllers/areas

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am developing an MVC3 application where some users are supposed to edit Events. Both 'administrators' and 'promoters' should be able to edit their events. The view is the same. I created an area for my administrators and promoters because they have quite different options.. My structure is a little like this

```
/admin/events/edit/1
/promoter/events/edit/1
```

In both areas I am using a different controller because the layout page should be different in the promoters/administrators area. Offcourse this leads to duplication and this where I am looking for a better solution. The views I could put in the 'Shared' folder but how do I prevent having two methods (one in each controller) that serve up the same view? A few options:

- Subclass both controllers from same base class that implements event editing. This works only once offcourse as you can have only base class. If I have other shared features this should all go into the baseclass.
- Delegate the edit functionality from both controllers to another class (EditEventController?)
- Use AJAX forms so the page is only updated partially. This complicates the situation.

In short: **how can I share edit pages among different areas/controllers in a MVC 3 application?**

@Added as the comment was too small:

I am using area's for roles because i want certain views of the site for that role. Like an admin area with subsections events/users and all other admin stuff. In this admin area i have a eventscontroller to handle the events section of the admin area. Another area is that of the promoter. It seemed like a logical division of the site (since I can control the layout for example per area and i can use a baseclass controller to require certain roles). Are you saying that this is not practical? I like the idea a single event controller but how do I for example get a different layoutpage/menu depending on the current role??

Answer (score 0):

It should be in the one controller. Sounds like you are mixing "areas" up with roles and routing.

Both those URL's should map to the one action method, not different controllers/areas.

"Events" should be an area, and use `[Authorize]` attribute or a custom attribute to allow it to be visible by both administrators and promoters.

Try and create an area for each logical component in your application, or if you prefer DDD-speak, each "aggregate".

So in your Events area, you could have a route like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Default",                                             
                "{role}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",                   
                new { controller = "Events", action = "Index", id = "" },
                new { role = new RoleBasedRouteConstraint() } // or you could use regex..
            );
```

And use a route constraint on the role route token to restrict to the string values corresponding to the roles, in addition to the roles-based authorization you would have in the controller.

Comment: How would this work out would I have urls like '/admin/event/edit/1' that would map to the event controller? How do i find out under which role the controller is accessed then?

Comment: @Gluip - you can use `[Authorize(Roles="Admin,Promoter")]` on your controller - is that what you mean?